# Flask-frozen don’t work whereas flask is ok

Tags: python, flask

I have a website using Flask. The main program is pretty long, so I’ve used [a paste](http://paste.tdct.org/index.php?hk) to show you the code. When I run it with `./site serve --debug` it works perfectly, but I can’t freeze it with Flask-frozen. I have this error :

```
$ ./site build                       
Building website...
./site:240: MimetypeMismatchWarning: Filename extension of u'sitemap.xml' (type application/xml) does not match Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  freezer.freeze()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./site", line 346, in <module>
    parser.dispatch()
  File "/home/guillaume/nicolas.perriault.net/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/helpers.py", line 53, in dispatch
    return dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/guillaume/nicolas.perriault.net/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/dispatching.py", line 123, in dispatch
    for line in lines:
  File "/home/guillaume/nicolas.perriault.net/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/dispatching.py", line 199, in _execute_command
    for line in result:
  File "/home/guillaume/nicolas.perriault.net/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh/dispatching.py", line 182, in _call
    result = args.function(*positional, **keywords)
  File "./site", line 240, in build
    freezer.freeze()
  File "/home/guillaume/nicolas.perriault.net/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py", line 140, in freeze
    new_filename = self._build_one(url)
  File "/home/guillaume/nicolas.perriault.net/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_frozen/__init__.py", line 250, in _build_one
    % (response.status, url))
ValueError: Unexpected status '500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR' on URL /403.html
```

If I delete the part about 403.html in site.py, I have the same error with 404, then 500, then contact.html, then /. And I can’t find why. Is there anybody who has an idea ?

Comment: What is in your templates? May be some `base.html`? Try addressing `/403.html` while running `./site serve --debug`. Is there any error?

Comment: No error when I go on `403.html`
I have a `base.html`, but I don’t think the bug comes from him. Do you want to see the code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable testing while freezing your application. It should produce more information about error.

```
@command
def build():
    """ Builds this site.
    """
    print("Building website...")
    app.debug = False
    app.testing = True
    asset_manager.config['ASSETS_DEBUG'] = False
    freezer.freeze()
    local("cp ./static/*.ico ./build/")
    local("cp ./static/*.txt ./build/")
    local("cp ./static/*.xml ./build/")
    print("Done.")
```

Frozen-flask uses `app.test_client()` look at it's [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.test_client).

Comment: Thanks a lot. With this I’ve found an error in the code. How to fix it ? Delete the bad code. :D

Comment: I guess it is http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/flask-assets/. It's a pitty that paste is dead:/